# Getting link to GMB review for someone else s business

Tags: google-my-business

I’m trying to educate a local business referral group on creating a habit of writing a Google My Business Review when business is passed between members.

I’m expecting a hurdle at the start will be to collect and publish their GMB review link.

Is there a way to get such a link from the GMB page if NOT being the page owner? It does not have to be a shortened link, just any link that works like the one that can be retrieved from your own GMB page.

Answer (score 3):

If you search for the business in Google and it appears on the right, there's a link to share the listing. You need to click on the 3 dots (1) and click Share (2).

If you open the copied URL in a new window, it'll appear as expected.

[image]

Comment: This is the link to the GMB profile, but I'm looking to get the link that opens the review popup. The owner can generate this, but I'm looking for someone else to be able to create it (or a reason why that should not be possible)

Comment: @jdog If you use the method above and click on the reviews link (e.g. 385 Google reviews) it will open a pop-up. 

If you copy the new URL in the address bar, you can share that and the pop-up of the reviews will be open by default.

Comment: I tried that here and the url still does not open the review popup https://g.co/kgs/WGbS8q

Comment: Try [this](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=589670984&rlz=1C5CHFA_enNZ830NZ830&q=Golden+Sands+Painting+-+Residential+and+Commercial+painting+in+Papamoa&ludocid=11835043298165659244&lsig=AB86z5XxNF-pQsLhUNVZv7R20sea&kgs=51d12cc4644c2a0c&shndl=-1&shem=lsp&source=sh/x/kp/local/m1/1#lrd=0x491aadafc86051ed:0xa43e852cc888166c,1,,,,) URL. I know it's long, but that works for me. Perhaps use a URL shortener if too long.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting and I learned a lot from this. When I referred to the "opens the review popup" - I was meaning the dialogue that allows you to write a review, not see the reviews.

When I tried my own review link, it seems to consist of the Maps place url and '/review/' appended. But trying this on someone else's Google Maps place url doesn't open the "leave a review" dialogue either

Comment: I see. You can always click the **Write a review** button found top right which will open the dialogue box. If you then copy this new URL, that should open the dialogue box by default as seen [here](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=589670984&rlz=1C5CHFA_enNZ830NZ830&q=Golden+Sands+Painting+-+Residential+and+Commercial+painting+in+Papamoa&ludocid=11835043298165659244&lsig=AB86z5XxNF-pQsLhUNVZv7R20sea&kgs=51d12cc4644c2a0c&shndl=-1&shem=lsp&source=sh/x/kp/local/m1/1#lrd=0x491aadafc86051ed:0xa43e852cc888166c,3,,,,).

The user will need to be logged in to Google to leave one, however.

Comment: Indeed it does!!!